# Phonegap file transfer plugin causing the Android build to fail

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm working on a mobile application for using Phonegap/Cordova, I'm using the file transfer plugin to upload photos from the photo library.

The iOS build was a success, while the Android build is giving me an error.

I'm not sure what's causing the build to fail and how to prevent that failure.

Here's the build log:
http://freetexthost.com/orbg5lm0en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-file-transfer` has a dependency for `cordova-plugin-file` 5.0.0, which is not compatible with your cordova-android version, it requires cordova-android 6.3.0 or newer. So you have two options:

1. Update your cordova-android 6.3.0 or newer (I would recommend 6.4.0)
2. Downgrade `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` to 1.6.3 as the dependency for `cordova-plugin-file` will be to an older version of the plugin that should work with your current platform

To update cordova-android you have to remove and re add it (beware that if you made some manual change on the project you will lose it)

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

To downgrade the plugin you also have to remove it first

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.6.3
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give me the fastest terminal command for both? just like phonegp add plugin PLUGINNAME. how can I downgrade to a specific version? and which one is the safest way to avoid any conflicts on the current iOS build?

Comment: Thank you! will apply it and get back asap.

Comment: I'm facing an issue with the ios11 status bar pushing the view down, on first launch, but when i hit an input, it pushes the view back to the normal state. any ideas please?

Comment: Check this blog post, specially the part about viewport-fit=cover. https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/

Comment: Hi, I tried it, and it's not working! Do you want me to open another question so I can add some screenshots, and my code? Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Sure, and also mention if you are using the cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: A new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848601/ios-11-status-bar-pushing-the-view-down-by-20px