# iOS 11 Status bar pushing the view down by 20px

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm facing an issue with the iOS 11 status bar pushing the view down on first launch, but when i hit an input, it pushes the view back to the normal state.

I added `viewport-fit=cover` but it didn't fix the issue.

I'm using  cordova-plugin-statusbar

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~1.0.1" />
```

Screenshots of the issue then when pushed back to normal:

[image]

I'm using Framework7 for the UI, and some plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.3.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 "PushPlugin"
```

And here's my config.xml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="APPPACKAGENAME" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Mayday</name>
    <description>
        Senior Project By Mohamad Fala
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Mohamad Fala
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="content:///*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
      <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/ldpi.png"/>
<icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/mdpi.png"/>
<icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/hdpi.png"/>
<icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xhdpi.png"/>
<icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xxhdpi.png"/>
<icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xxxhdpi.png"/>

<splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-ldpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-mdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-hdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png"/>
<splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png"/>

        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
        </feature>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
      <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" height="1024"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167"/>
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>

<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <access origin="content:///*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
            <string>need to photo library access to upload pictures for posts</string>
        </edit-config>
        <feature name="StatusBar">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Keyboard">
            <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVKeyboard" />
        </feature>
    </platform>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" spec="https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="~1.8.0">
        <param name="SENDER_ID" value="981753167590" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Try updating statusbar plugin to 2.3.0 (latest). The problem might be an old bug

Comment: @jcesarmobile I tried, but it's still pushing down the navbar.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about this, never saw something like that. Can you try without the statusbar plugin? Are you using some UI framework? also, provide the config.xml to see statusbar preferences if any and if you are using some code for the statusbar

Comment: @jcesarmobile Edited and added the requested codes.

Comment: I think it's some Framework7 issue. I've found this issue, but it's closed and don't really understand why https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7/issues/1811. There are a few more statusbar issues there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, it was working fine on my IOS 10.3 and had the issue on IOS 11.3.

Fixed adding these entries on config.xml:

```html
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#4183D7" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Comment: late to the party, but these lines do not work for me (iOs 12.2, cordova 8). Looks like the status is overlapping my app :(